# Select most recent record from multiple tables by using a view

Tags: mysql

I have two MySQL tables with identical structure where I store data:

```
tableA(id, value, updatedAt)
tableB(id, value, updatedAt)
```

A third party application does `SELECT value FROM myTable WHERE id = 123`. Now I'd like that query to look in both `tableA` and `tableB` and return the `value` from the one with the most recent `updatedAt` datetime.

- For a given `id` it may be in only one of the tables, both or none.
- Those tables are big, in the order of 500M records each.
- There's about 2k/s selects from `myTable` and those need to be fast.
- There's about 200k/h updates to `tableA` and `tableB`. Updates must not ruin select performance but need not be fast.
- The data tables are updated from independent feeds, that's why they're separated.

I tried to create a view.

```
CREATE VIEW myTable AS
(select * from tableA)
UNION
(select * from tableB)
ORDER BY updatedAt DESC LIMIT 1
```

But since I use `UNION` MySQL will use the `TEMPTABLE` algorithm and, apart from not working, it's very slow.

My second attempt don't support if the `id` is only present in one of the tables (assuming I use the wrong JOIN?), besides it looks quite ugly.

```
CREATE VIEW myTable AS
SELECT
  IF(a.updatedAt > b.updatedAt, a.id, b.id) AS id,
  IF(a.updatedAt > b.updatedAt, a.value, b.value) AS value,
  IF(a.updatedAt > b.updatedAt, a.modifiedAt, b.updatedAt) AS updatedAt
FROM tableA AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe using the `MERGE` engine will work?

Comment: Why bother with a VIEW?

Comment: @Strawberry I can't change the SELECT statement made by the third party.  Could you elaborate what solution you have in mind without a view?

Comment: @Barmar When using UNION in the select for a view you can't use MERGE. And in my second attempt it's MERGE but there I have other issues.

Comment: @MyGGaN My suggestion is to create a new table using the `MERGE` storage engine *instead* of creating a view. I'm not sure what you mean by using `MERGE` in your second attempt. Are you confusing this with `JOIN`?

Comment: I didn't know you could create MEREGE tables as well, thanks @Barmar. I'll see if we can switch from InnoDB to MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 CREATE VIEW myTable AS
  SELECT
   IF(a.updatedAt > b.updatedAt, a.id, b.id) AS id,
   IF(a.updatedAt > b.updatedAt, a.value, b.value) AS VALUE,
   IF(a.updatedAt > b.updatedAt, a.modifiedAt, b.updatedAt) AS updatedAt
 FROM tableA a, tableB b;
```

Comment: This would work for small tables. But selecting from a Cartesian product derived from two large tables would take hours, or days even, when sub-second lookups are required.